# With strict types enabled, array_map converts types anyways

Tags: php, types, type-hinting

I've came across a really interesting bug in PHP 7.0.11 where `declare(strict_types=1);` enabled does not make the `array_map()` nor `array_walk()` aware of strict types. I read somewhere that by enabling strict types PHP also uses strict types in core functions, but this is not the case.
Look at this example code, it should throw TypeError exception:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

$myArray = [12, 'string value', 'another string value', 5];

array_map('validateMyArrayValues', $myArray);

function validateMyArrayValues(string $item)
{
    var_dump($item);
}
```

The `var_dump` result is:

```
test.php:13:
    string(2) "12"
test.php:13:
    string(12) "string value"
test.php:13:
    string(20) "another string value"
test.php:13:
    string(1) "5"
```

All the integer values are typecasted into strings which is obviously an issue. This raises the question should I drop `declare(strict_types=1);` altogether and use `is_*` functions and throwing exceptions?

Comment: you could argue if you want *strict* types, dont use php. one of its *advantages* is its loose types

Comment: @raina77ow yes, yes it is kinda weird bheaviour. Strangely with int it works properly. Actually I would really happy if anybody could post a bug report to PHP dev group since PHP 7.1 is also affected; and I am not so good at writing proper bug reports.

Comment: @Dagon right, but every programing language have its strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: @raina77ow This is so sad. As long as these function have this bug I think I will stick with the good old `foreach` and do the validation inside the loop. Thank you the reassurance in this topic @raina77ow.

Comment: This does look like a php bug https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L1636

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a bug (hat tip to [Room 11](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) for pointing me in the right direction)

Here's the [Strict Types RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints_v5). It's really, really long and the most contentious RFC in the history of PHP (and I'm being serious). Here's the relevant portions cut out for you

> This proposal builds in weak type checking by default (using the same rules), for **internal and user functions**.

- 

> A significant portion of the PHP community appears to favor fully-strict types. However, adding strictly type-checked scalar type declarations would cause a few problems: 
> Existing code which (perhaps unintentionally) took advantage of PHP's weak typing would break if functions it calls added scalar type declarations to parameters. This would complicate the addition of scalar type declarations to the parameters of functions in existing codebases, particularly libraries.

So this isn't a bug. This was part of the grand compromise that made this possible (baby steps towards stricter typing, if you will). Functions ignore strict typing. Yes, it's inconsistent with other languages (a fact the RFC notes in detail), but that's how the PHP community decided it should be for now.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a case of weak type hinting ([demo](https://eval.in/709627)). Any integer can be converted into string, but only 'numeric' strings are cast to integers.

Comment: This is the Big-Ahaa moment. Thank you for your clarification @Machavity. I am currently reading Strict Types RFC it is really interesting.